# Rails Whenever gem not executing repetitive crontab task with Ubuntu and Docker Compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, cron, whenever

I'm trying to run a repetitive task using the Whenever gem for my rails app. It is running in a Docker container created using Docker Compose and  hosted on an Ubuntu server.

I can successfully create and update the crontab file using the Whenever gem but it doesn't seem to be executing the task.

The task I want to execute repetitively in the background while the app is running is:

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Property
```

I usually execute this command successfully from the terminal after creating a web run container using 'docker-compose run web bash'. This reindexes my ElasticSearch server using the searchkick gem.

The relevant versions are below:

```
- ruby 2.7.2p137
- rails (6.0.3.6)
- elasticsearch (6.8.3)
  - elasticsearch-api (= 6.8.3)
  - elasticsearch-transport (= 6.8.3)
- searchkick (4.4.4)
  - activemodel (>= 5)
  - elasticsearch (>= 6)
  - hashie
- whenever (1.0.0)
  - chronic (>= 0.6.3)
```

Cron is installed using the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y curl \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    cron \
    vim \
    nano \
    postgresql \
    postgresql-contrib \
    postgresql-client
```

The Dockerfile runs a script when the container is created:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

The script (entrypoint.sh) creates a crontab file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# For development check if the gems as installed, if not, then uninstall them.
if ! [ bundle check ]; then
    bundle install
fi

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Yarn - Check Files.
yarn install --check-files

# Create empty crontab file.
crontab -l | { cat; echo ""; } | crontab -

# Update crontab file using whenever command.
bundle exec whenever --set 'environment=production' --update-crontab

# Run the command - runs any arguments passed into this entrypoint file.
exec "$@"
```

The 'bundle exec whenever --set 'environment=production' --update-crontab' command above updates the crontab file as per the schedule.rb file below:

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

# Reindex Property records every 3 mins.
every 3.minutes do
    rake "searchkick:reindex CLASS=Property"
end
```

I've also tried using this:

```
every 3.minutes do
    command "cd /myapp && rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Property"
end
```

When I execute 'docker-compose run web bash' to use the rails terminal, I see this response at the end:

```
no crontab for root
[write] crontab file updated
```

To check that it was created correctly, I view the crontab file in the rails app with 'crontab -l' and it shows:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2021-04-24 13:07:12 +0000
PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /myapp && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Property --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2021-04-24 13:07:12 +0000
```

Update: After using `cron service status` and `cron service start`, the logs in myApp/log/cron_log.log show the following:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
```

So it seems to have set up the crontab file and the cronjob is trying to run but it is not finding rake-13.0.3. I'm going to check if this is an issue with the bundler gem version versus what is in the gemfile.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: when use rails terminal, did you try to check `service cron status` ?

Comment: @LamPhan, thank you. I've tried `service cron status` now and the response is `[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!`

Comment: then run `service cron start ` and check `cat log/cron_log.log` after 3 minutes.

Comment: @LamPhan, thanks, getting closer now. At least now a log is being generated which is helpful. Updated above. I'm checking the bundler issue now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. you can run `cron` to start cron service (linux) in your `entrypoint.sh`

```
# Update crontab file using whenever command.
cron && bundle exec whenever --set 'environment=production' --update-crontab
```

2. schedule don't know the gems path so the `Bundler::GemNotFound` error be throw, to solve this, you can avoid missing paths by setting all ENV in `schedule.rb`

```rb
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }
# ...
```